# styling the default html checkboxes

Tags: html, css

This HTML code shows two checkboxes next to each other

```
<div id="mr_mrs">
    <ul class="mr_mrs form-no-clear">
        <li id="mr" class="popular-category">
            <label for="Mr" id="mr">Mr</label>
            <span><input name="Mr" id="Mr" type="checkbox" /></span>
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </li>
        <li id="mrs" class="popular-category">
            <label for="Mrs" id="mrs">Mrs</label>
                <span><input name="Mrs" id="Mrs" type="checkbox" /></span>
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to customize the checkboxed to square and on selecting the checkbox fill some color to it. IMAGE BELOW

How can this be done ?[image]

Comment: What CSS have you tried already?

Comment: tried this... http://jsfiddle.net/Lter04p8/

Comment: @Learning your jsfiddle would be a great thing to add to your question. It looks like you've got it mostly working from what I saw, what do you need help with or want to know more about?

Comment: yes, you code is working fine, so what is the issue

Comment: problem is need two checkbox next to each other and clicking on text should also select the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

To sit the two controls next to each other, set their display to inline block: `display: inline-block`. (Default for `div` is block display.)

To enable the user to check the box by clicking the label text, there are a couple options. Both are shown in the example below.

1. `<label>` is parent to the text and checkbox.
2. Use `<label for="myId">some text</label><input id="myId">` to associate the label to the input.*

*Note: when using the for/id method, it's label-for and input-id. I noticed in the example the id was applied to both elements, an id should be unique to the page.

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>Box 1<input type="checkbox"></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for="myId">Box 2</label>
  <input id="myId" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: onclick of checkbox.. instead of tickmark, how to fill color... image attached in question

Comment: @Learning Doesn't your jsfiddle already change the color when checked?

Comment: it does not add up another checkbox and only checkbox is clickable

Comment: I'm not following. sorry. Can you explain: "it does not add up another checkbox"? Regarding clickable text, did you try the code snippet in the answer?

Comment: tried your answer ... its working ... in the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Lter04p8/ adding another checkbox next to the previous one.. does not show's up

Comment: I'm unsure how to help. @vicbyte provided an answer with another example of custom checkbox and I've tried to help explain how to display block elements inline and make label text clickable. I've flagged this question as unclear. If you can help us understand what you're asking, please edit your question to **clearly** and **specifically** state what problem you're trying to solve.